# Solution to this 2nd order linear homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

How do I find a solution to:
$$i p(t)\ddot x-\left[p(t)^2+i\dot p(t)\right]\dot x+2ip(t)^3x=0\ ,$$
where $p(t)$ is some chosen smooth function, and the overdot represents derivative with respect to $t$.

Can anyone see a solution for a particular non-trivial choice of $p(t)$?

Comment: You can choose some function $x$ and solve the first order equation in $p$ (unfortunately nonlinear).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I would prefer to go the other way, i.e. choose a $p$ and solve for $x$ since I want to avoid nonlinear ODEs.

Comment: Just suggesting an alternative line of attack.